# Open file with app as duplicate

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, nsworkspace

The idea is that I have a template of a file that needs to be opened but it should behave as if only the contents of the file were opened instead of the file itself.

The difference for the user should be, that he needs to select a place to save the file to instead of just overwriting the file that was opened.

Similar behaviour can be seen in the Preview app. When duplicating a function Preview will open the same file in a new window. Upon saving the file the user needs to specify where to save it to.

As far as I can see `NSWorkspace` does not support such behaviour out of the box. Does anybody know a workaround for that? I'd appreciate it!

## EDIT

In my case I don't know where the user wants to save the file to when he or she is done with it. Currently I am only copying the file to a hidden folder in the user's home directory and then I open the copy so that the original file can not be overwritten.

The resulting behaviour is:
- the user does not see where the file is located
- upon saving and closing the application that the file was edited in the user will not find the file ever again.

**Workaround**: I guess for now I will ask the user where she wants to save it before opening it, which seems kind of redundant to me as it could very well be, that she will not want to save it. Hopefully I will find a better solution soon.

Comment: You want to open such a new document in your own app? Or in some other app? Will the open action be initiated in your app? Or another? For what it's worth, the OS has built-in support for something like what you're describing. See the "Stationery pad" checkbox in the Get Info window for a file in the Finder.

Comment: @KenThomases My app is calling NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(..) with a url and an appropriate application to open that url. So your answer is exactly what I need. I'm quite baffled that after more than a decade of programming and using macOS I have never noticed nor read about this stationery pad feature. :D

Comment: It's an ancient feature from the days of the Classic Mac OS. I didn't find any modern API for marking a file as a stationery pad. Presumably, one could still use the File Manager API to set the relevant bit in the Finder flags of a file. Also, just so you know, all that the system does when a stationery pad file is opened is to make a copy and open that copy. You could do that, too. Note that the app won't require that the user specify a location when saving, because the app already associates the document with an existing file (the automatic copy).

Comment: This sounded promising at first but it is truly not working just as I first expected. I'm already copying the file so @KenThomases was right, that there is not much of a difference. Noteworthy nonetheless is the fact, that the stationary pad flag only affects the users direct interaction with the file e.g through the Finder. But when calling NSWorkspace to open the file, the flag will be ignored. So this is not my problem's solution but still – setting the flag via Apple Script is described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39490/make-a-file-a-stationery-pad-via-command-line

Comment: Are you trying to open the new document in a specific, known app? Perhaps it could be scripted or provides a Service that you could invoke.

Comment: It depends on the file type and the default app that is set to open this file. So I can't tell which app the file is going to be opened in.

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be able to send an "open contents" (`'ocon'`/`kAEOpenContents`) Apple Event to the target app.

Comment: I'm currently reading through the documentation as I can't find an example for sending an Apple Event to a specific App. I have to admit that I am baffled at the complexity of such a small task. This seems as complex as Metal Graphics programming just less well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by sending an "open contents" (`'ocon'`/`kAEOpenContents`) Apple Event to the target app. The easiest way is probably to use the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The normal way to use the Scripting Bridge requires that you know in advance which app you want to target and generate an Objective-C header from its scripting interface definition. However, you should be able to use it "raw". For example, something like this:

```
SBApplication *app = [SBApplication applicationWith...:...]; // there are method to take a PID, a bundle ID, or a URL
[app activate];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithString:@"foobar"];
[app sendEvent:kCoreEventClass id:kAEOpenContents parameters:keyDirectObject, desc, nil];
```

The `NSAppleEventDescriptor` object is the contents payload, in this case the string "foobar". You can use other methods to create different types of payloads. If you use the generic one and need a descriptor type, you can look in the headers in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers (e.g. AEDataModel.h or AERegistry.h).

Comment: With your help I was able to open the app. Thank you so much for that. Bust still - the example of course will not cause opening the right content. Unfortunately I have worked on this for hours and I could not figure out how to open the contents of files. As far as I understand I need a typeAlias descriptor. But non of my attempts worked. `[[NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithFileURL:urls[0]] coerceToDescriptorType:typeAlias];`, `[[ScriptingBridgeHelper descriptorWithBookmarkDataForFileURL:urls[0]] coerceToDescriptorType:typeAlias];` as described in another question on stack overflow.

Comment: What is the type of the content of the file? Is it an image? Text? I think you want to read the file's contents into a data object and use `+descriptorWithDescriptorType:data:` with an appropriate type. For PNG image data, that may entail converting to TIFF data and using `typeTIFF`, for example. Can you confirm that if you drag the type of data you expect your file contents to have from some editor/viewer app to the icon of an app you expect to target, that the app opens a new document with those contents?

Comment: You may also be able to get the type using `NSHFSTypeOfFile()` or, with a dictionary of file attributes, `fileHFSTypeCode`.